# Why is my RVM gem cache so large (4.3GB)?

Tags: ruby, rvm

Self explanatory.  Any way to lower this safely?

```
$ du -sh ~/.rvm/gems
4.3G
```

Comment: Some suggestions: install gems without rdoc and ri; remove old gems with `gem cleanup`

Comment: Thanks. I tried `gem cleanup` and it didn't affect the size.

Comment: Did you try to install them without rdoc and ri? it would greatly help you IMHO

Comment: How many gems do you have? Everything? My entire 1.9.3 and 2.1.0 installation using rbenv is only 1.5G, including ~164 gems for each, and that's with full documentation.

Comment: What is the output of `du -h ~/.rvm/gems | sort -h | tail -n10`?

Comment: `Any way to lower this safely?` => `rm -rf .rvm/gems` => `bundle install`

Comment: @mdesantis https://gist.github.com/eriknomitch/014fed7c6b13f70dfe80 I will try to purge all and install them without rdoc.

Comment: `rvm list`...  How many Rubies do you have?  Do you need them all?  Cruft accumulates as time goes on...  `rvm cleanup all` may get you something if you've removed old Rubies but not their gems.